# VB alternative/equivalent for development of Windows apps in Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development

I want to develop a simple form for an Invoice for the user to use on Windows. I learnt how to do it using Visual basic in Windows. It's the simplest way to make a GUI for Windows I suppose. I am going to link it to a database at the backend.

I want an alternative or equivalent software that will provide me with similar drag-and-drop feature enabled programing and GUI designing that will help me crate an application that will run on Windows.

Comment: [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) is the IDE for building VB.NET applications on Linux. It has GUI building support through GTK UI. See [this page](http://monodevelop.com/documentation/stetic_gui_designer)

Comment: @Samik You may want to post this as an answer, as I think currently it's the best "answer" here. If you do, you may want to mention that Mono and MonoDevelop do support Visual Basic 8 (and the resultant .NET binaries will run on Ubuntu, Windows, and any other platform that has a .NET Framework implementation). You may also want to provide information about how to code in Visual Basic "under the hood" of an application whose interface is made with Stetic.

Comment: @EliahKagan Actually Stetic is the reason for posting this as a comment. While Stetic works fine with `C#`, I don't know if any implementation of Stetic is there for `VB.NET`. But it is quite possible to code GTK based applications with `VB.NET` in `MonoDevelop` if OP is interested to code by hand. One option could be [GLADE# code generator](http://eric.extremeboredom.net/2005/06/08/203) which generates code based on Glade files, but I don't know if that works with new `.ui` files generated by Glade. I'm sure you can add some extra knowledge if you post that as an answer, then I'll delete mine

Comment: @Samik You can combine C# and Visual Basic 8 in the same program. I'm not sure the best way to do this to effectively have a program with a Stetik GUI, where most of the code is in VB, because I have never used Stetik myself. Hopefully somebody can combine all this into an answer (or failing that, perhaps moderators could consolidate these comments).

Comment: @Samik...I found KBasic...is it good? i tried creating a basic form but when i click on a component say button,i cant place it anywhere on the form :/

Comment: @Nirmik first of all, I'm not the suitable guy to throw an opinion on KBasic as I've never used it before. But after visiting the website it looks quite promising, though I don't know if it is binary-compatible with VB.NET i.e. the `.dll` generated by KBasic will work with VB's and vice-versa. But other than that it looks professional grade for it's features.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted **Real Studio** is a full-featured, cross-platform software development tool suited to creating a wide range of applications, from utilities to enterprise-class applications. Real Studio is the only object-oriented, cross-platform software development tool that enables users at all levels to create powerful, stand-alone, native applications. For more info about Real Studio  [See This Site](http://www.realsoftware.com/realstudio/).

Also you can look at QT ( cross-platform application framework that is widely used for developing application software with a graphical user interface (GUI)) would be an option.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: Real Studio is commercial and quite expensive. Do you by chance have any connection with them? I ask because your post sounds like marketing talk to me and is taken copy-paste from the company's site. No offense, but it's always good to be clear about any commercial interest involved.

Comment: @Floyd I'm just trying to help.  I came across this the other day when I was searching for something else.  So no connection, plus if software is good, there is no harm in buying, since not everything is free (just an opinion) :)

Comment: As said, no offense intended (well, the copy-paste from the site made me wonder if someone from marketing was at work here). What can you say about the strengths of real studio? RAD for C / C++ would be nice.

Comment: @Floyd Non taking, we're all here to help, in whichever way we can :)

Comment: Real Studio is commercial, but nothing in the original questions says that is a problem.  Comparatively speaking, there are few if any cross-platform tools that are as easy to use as Real Studio.  And starting at $99 it can hardly be called "quite expensive". It's certainly less expensive than other equivalent commercial tools.  Free software is great, but for some people time is money and it is worth it to pay to get a supported, easy-to-use tool.  -- Paul, Real Software Developer Evangelist

Answer (score 2):

For RAD (rapid application development) under Linux, Windows etc. i would have a look at the [Lazarus Project](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/), which is an open source development environment for pascal which generates native code and has very fast development. It could be called the open source alternative to the commercial Delphi RAD environment.

It's also right there in the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install lazarus lazarus-doc
```

Comment: You may want to edit your answer to include links.

Answer (score 0):

Go for JABACO which is Java based and pure Visual Basic 6 alternative 
I was try on Jabaco Simply same way as VB6 programming 
So If you are looking for creating Forms Reports etc It is good