# What is the alternative for the following programs?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

What alternatives are there for the following programs?

- Internet download manager
- Yahoo Messenger
- Visual Basic

What software do I need after installing Ubuntu?

Comment: software you need according to your needs and daily work we can't answer you for something we ignore!! For what will you use Ubuntu?! What things you do in your pc?

Comment: see here: http://alternativeto.net/

Answer (score 2):

For download manager you can use [steadyflow](https://launchpad.net/steadyflow) or [jdownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) or [flareget](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flareget/)

You can use **empathy**  instead of yahoo messenger and much more. Empathy is a found by default in Ubuntu . To learn how to use check [this](http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/04/04/empathy-chat-messenger-tutorial/)

For VB check [VB alternative/equivalent for development of Windows apps in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148986/vb-alternative-equivalent-for-development-of-windows-apps-in-ubuntu)

Comment: No please iam honor to just be a friend a teacher is a big word for me